# How do you execute a command on a remote system insde a BASH script?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, remote-execution

As part of an intricate BASH script, I'd like to execute a command on a remote system from within the script itself.

Right now, I run the script which tailors files for the remote system and uploads them, then through a ssh login I execute a single command.

So for full marks:

- How do I log into the remote system from the bash script (i.e. pass the credentials in non-interactively)?
- How can I execute a command (specifically "chmod 755 /go && /go") from within the script?

Comment: Set up [SSH key pairs](http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/) (broken, [here's the archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20090331164913/http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/)) and just run the command like: ssh user@host 'command' There are, of course other interconnects available, but few portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [Tim Post's answer](http://web.archive.org/web/20090331164913/http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/):

Setup public keys and then you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@host "chmod 755 /go && /go"
```

Comment: combine your answers and it's much more complete.